# Using Microsoft font files in Windows Store App

Tags: fonts, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

May I add Microsoft Times New Roman .ttf font file into my Windows Store App package ? I just need to render text using this font, I don't want to modify it or distribute outside my program. Can I safe do this with Times New Roman license?

Comment: So is this question about the legality/ethics of including this font?

Comment: Yes, it's all about legality

Answer (score 0):

Surely all the systems you are distributing to will already have this font installed and you do not need to embed it.

Comment: Actually, I need to embed it because Windows Store App can't get phisical font file from system folder. My app using freetype c++ lib, which need font file bytes.